# How to deploy project with msdeploy instead of msbuild

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

Today I use msbuild to deploy a web application to an iis server. How can I do the same with msdeploy (command line)?

```
MSBuild.exe myproject.csproj
/P:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
/P:Password=pass
/P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true
/P:DeployOnBuild=True
/P:PublishProfile=deploytest
/P:DeployIISAppPath="Default Web site"
/P:MsDeployServiceUrl=my.server.com
/P:Configuration=Release
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends what you would like your workflow to be, if you want to package the output and deploy that seperately then you'll need to create a zip file from your build.

**Create Package**

Add the following to your msbuild command line to create a package:

```
/p:DeployTarget=Package
/p:PackageLocation=MyProject.zip
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
```

**Deploy Package**

```
msdeploy.exe 
    -verb:sync 
    -source:Package=MyProject.Zip 
    -destination:auto:ComputerName="my.server.com"
```

You might also want to promote from one deployed site to another.

**Clone Site**

```
msdeploy.exe
    -verb:sync
    -source:appHostConfig="my.server.com"
    -dest:appHostConfig="mynew.server.com"
```

Or you may already have a site that you want to target.

**Clone Application**

```
msdeploy.exe
    -verb:sync
    -source:iisApp="my.server.com/MyApp"
    -dest:iisApp="my.server.com/MyNewApp"
```

Comment: Is there a way to use web deploy only?

Comment: You can't build using msdeploy, but you can build and deploy using msbuild or you can build with msbuild and deploy with msdeploy.  I'm not sure of your use case here?

Comment: Ok. I think I get it now. I regarded msbuild to be the "old way to do it" and msdeploy the cleaner way. But when you put it that way it makes sense. Thanx!